# Obtaining Jenkins Artifacts for local builds

Tags: c#, jenkins

I am working on setting up a CI implementation at my company, and have successfully set up a simple stream of applications and references in Jenkins, using the [artifact copy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to provide references from one project to another.

This all works fine, however I am struggling to find an answer to one element of this process, which I'm sure must have been solved by someone.

When I am working locally making changes to the projects, is there any automated or semi-automated way to get the latest artifacts from Jenkins and copy them to my local machine to be referenced by my local build?

Currently, my references exist in a folder named _ExternalReferences in the root of the solution, and Jenkins copies specified references to that folder. Is there any solution besides manually downloading the assemblies from Jenkins and copying them into my local directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean: How do you build your project on your own laptop using the same build scripts/tools as Jenkins does because you cannot use "Copy artifact plugin" when you don't builder under Jenkins?

This is a very good question. Because downloading of artifacts is done by Jenkins outside your build script, before the build script even runs, you have to provide something similar for making local/developer builds.

You can make a script which your developers can call (or make target if you are using make), which downloads build artifacts from Jenkins by calling something like:

```
curl -sfO $JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifacts/PATH/TO/FILE
```

OTOH, if you make a script / make target like this, shouldn't you use it also when building in Jenkins? Why complicate things by having two different methods for getting the "external references"?  And in my opinion, you should use the same script / make target in Jenkins too.

Using the "Copy artifact plugin" does not provide any benefit other than being easy to set up. Actually, there is one benefit: because the artifacts are copied via the existing pipe Jenkins has to the slave, it works even in environments where the slaves run in a network segment that blocks them from connecting to the master. This is the reason I have to use it at work.